# raise e.__class__( ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'face picture from actor'

Tags: reactjs, django, forms, django-models, django-views

in **windows 10** , i'm using **react-router-dom 5.2.0** and **react-redux 7.2.5** and **react 17.0.2** and **axios 0.21.4** and **WebStorm 2023.1.3 IDE** and **PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2** and **djangorestframework==3.14.0** and **Django==4.2.4** and **djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.3.0**

1. **frontend**

Consider - manager_room.js:

```
 {loadingGetProductCategories ? <Loader /> : errorGetProductCategories ? <div className="alert alert-danger" >{errorGetProductCategories}</div>:productCategoriesRedux ? <div className="mb-3">
                                <div className="form-label" htmlFor="categories">select category</div>
                                <select className="form-select" id="categories" value={category} options={productCategoriesRedux} onChange={(e) => handleChangeNormalSelect(e)} multiple>
                                    {productCategoriesRedux && productCategoriesRedux.map && productCategoriesRedux.map(category => (

                                            <option value={category.title}>{category.title}</option>

                                    ))}
                                </select>


                            </div>:""}
```

2.**backend**

Consider - product_views.py:

```
@api_view(http_method_names=['POST'])
@csrf_exempt
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def upload_new_product(request):
    try:
        data = request.data
        file = request.FILES
        id = data.get('id')
        CustomUser = get_user_model()
        user = CustomUser.objects.filter(id=id).first()
        print("do")
        reqUser = request.user
        if user == reqUser:
            product = Product.objects.create(user=user, name=data.get('productName'), image=file.get('productImage'), brand=data.get('brand'), description=data.get('description'), rating=data.get('rating'), price=data.get('price'), countInStock=data.get('countInStock'))

            product.categories.set(data.getlist('category'))
            product.save()
            

            srz_data = ProductSerializer(instance=product, many=False)
            return Response(srz_data.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response({'detail': 'you are not this account\'s user'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)


    except APIException as err:
        return Response(str(err), status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

    else:
        print("Nothing went wrong")
    finally:
        print("The 'try except' is finished")
```

error is in line `product.categories.set(data.getlist('category'))` by raise:

```
 raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'face picture from actor'.
[03/Jan/2024 13:39:44] "POST /api/v1/products/upload_new_product/ HTTP/1.1" 500 130849
```

Actually the save category is not saved in `manyTmanyField` and it shows me the mentioned error

Consider - models.py:

```
def get_product_image_path(instance, filename):
    base_name = os.path.basename(filename)
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(base_name)
    rand_value = random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999)
    final_name = f"{instance.name}-{instance.brand}-{instance.category}-{rand_value}-imageProduct{ext}"
    return f"products_images/{instance.category}/{instance.brand}/{instance.name}/{final_name}"


class Product(models.Model):
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_product_image_path, null=True, blank=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    numReviews = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    countInStock = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(ProductCategory, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{str(self.name)} - {self.createdAt}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "product"
        verbose_name_plural = "products"
```

**Note** : *i guess this field* `categories = models.ManyToManyField(ProductCategory, blank=True)` *is* *the center of the error*.

I searched most of the questions in this forum and Google, but I didn't find the answer. Please answer me. I hope I don't encounter a typo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in how you send category data, django orm expect id but you are sendig categories name change it to id. If still want to send names try this:

```
       category_names = data.getlist('category')
        categories = [ProductCategory.objects.get_or_create(title=category)[0] for category in category_names]

        product.categories.set(categories)
        product.save()
```

Comment: Thank you very much @RezaTeymoori , this answer is wonderful and true and amazing and deserves many votes, and I hope you will be successful wherever you are in this world, fellow Iranian.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind words! I'm glad you found the answer helpful.Wishing you success and happiness as well,